# My ListView acitviity evrytime call previous arraylist when add new data in database

Tags: android, memory-management, arraylist

I create an activity thats populate from database and fill to ArrayList.
when add a new data in database and call listview activity thats change ArrayList to last with for example 6 and previous ArrayList  with 5 item.
when i finish activity use below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ListViewClass.this, AddClass.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        ListViewClass.this.onDestroy();
        //NamayeshListYadavar.this.finish();
```

but when call ListViewClass thasts save previous ArrayList  and new ArrayList and evrytime switch between two ArrayList.
When i debug my program show me 2 ArrayList with same name but different id and size.how to i can delete previous ArrayList when finish activity and call AddClass in my project?
Also i use

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();      
}
```

but in not work.
please help me  friends.
and sorry for bad english.
This is all of my oncreate code

all of my code is :

```html
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import com.blueprogrammers.utils.SomeUtils;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
public class NamayeshListYadavar extends HeaderFooter {
  //AlarmData[] daro_data;
   ArrayList<AlarmData> daro_data = new ArrayList<AlarmData>(); 
   Handler mHandler = new Handler();
  String myValue;
  List<AlarmData> alarmList;
  NamayeshListAdaptor adapter;
  ListView list;
  public String font1="byekan.ttf";
  public String font2="BMitraBd.ttf";
  private static final int RUN_EDIT = 1100;
  /*** 0 for vibre 1 for melody and 2 for melody and vivre***/
  int alarmtype = 2, vibre=0;
  Boolean animlockBoolean=false;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lldata);
   ViewGroup.inflate(this, R.layout.yadavar_list, vg);
   list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yadavar_listview);
   createCollection();
      adapter = new NamayeshListAdaptor(this,
                 R.layout.namayeshyadavar, daro_data);
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         list.setAdapter(adapter);
   list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
      android.view.View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     TextView tv = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.txtid);
              //String text = tv.getText().toString(); 
              myValue =  (String) tv.getText();
              Intent intent = new Intent(NamayeshListYadavar.this, EditYadavar.class);
              intent.putExtra("YADAVAR-ID", myValue);
              startActivity(intent);
              NamayeshListYadavar.this.finish();
              //startActivityForResult(intent, RUN_EDIT);     
    }
   });   

   Timer timer = new Timer();
   timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
       public void run() {
           new textSearh().execute();
       }
   }, 0, 500);
 }
 public void clickMe(View v){
  switch (v.getId()) {
  case R.id.txttarikhetmam:
   break;
  default:
   break;
  }
 }
 class textSearh extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();
  }
  protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
   
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     final SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("DaroPref", 0);
              final int del = preferences.getInt("delid", 9999);
              Boolean checkBoolean =preferences.getBoolean("delbol", false);
              if(checkBoolean){
               Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("delbol", false);
                editor.commit();
               deleteView(del);
              }
    }
   });
   return null;
  }
  protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {   
  }
 }
 private void createCollection() {
     DatabaseHandler db= new DatabaseHandler(this);
     alarmList = new ArrayList<AlarmData>();
     alarmList = db.getViewAlarm("SELECT AlarmID, idDrug, alarmTime , nameYadavar, done, alarmDate FROM Alarm where done =0");
     ArrayList<AlarmData> alarm_dat = new ArrayList<AlarmData>(alarmList);
     this.daro_data=alarm_dat;
      db.close();
    }
 public void deleteView(final int del){
  createCollection2();
   Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                 NamayeshListYadavar.this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right
             );
   try{
   anim.setDuration(500);
   list.getChildAt(del).startAnimation(anim );
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      createCollection2();
        adapter = new NamayeshListAdaptor(NamayeshListYadavar.this,
                   R.layout.namayeshyadavar, daro_data);
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           list.setAdapter(adapter);
      
   
   }
   }, anim.getDuration());
   }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    
   }  
 }
 public void btnbtnClick(View v)
  {
   switch (v.getId()) {
   case R.id.btnadd:
   Intent intent = new Intent(NamayeshListYadavar.this, TanzimSaat.class);
   intent.putExtra("CLASS-TYPE", "NamayeshListYadavar");
   startActivityForResult(intent, RUN_EDIT);
   //startActivityForResult(intent, RUN_EDIT);
           
   break;
   case R.id.btnbar:
    this.finish();
    break;
   default:
   break;
  }
  }
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       
  this.finish();
    }
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     switch (requestCode) {
      case RUN_EDIT:
       
        createCollection2();
        adapter = new NamayeshListAdaptor(this,
                   R.layout.namayeshyadavar, daro_data);
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           list.setAdapter(adapter);
            break;
     }
 }
 }
```

**Finally i fixed problem by add below code**

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    timer.cancel();
    this.finish();
}
```

Timer is my problem